# Adobe Air development in webstorm

Tags: javascript, html, air, webstorm

Just trying to get familiar with Adobe Air and JavaScript so I've downloaded a trial of WebStorm.

I'm following a menu tutorial from here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/quickstart/articles/adding_menus.html but somehow WebStorm does not recognise some of the Air variables. For example:

```
air.NativeWindow.supportsMenu;
air.NativeApplication.supportsDockIcon;
```

In both of these (and other) cases air and NativeWindow are recognised, but the 3rd variable (supportsMenu, supportsDockIcon) are reported as "not recognised variables", which is strange because they are perfectly valid according to Air API reference.

Is there a way to fix that?

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I Know WebStorm does not have support for Adobe AIR, which means it doesn't know about the AIR API variables.  If you pulled in a reference like AIRAliases.js, it would "know" about the aliases defined there, though.

I would love to be wrong about this. Can you point me to a reference that says WebStorm supports AIR or explains how to support AIR in WebStorm?

Comment: You are right: WebStorm doesn't support Air.
The only IDE from JetBrains that supports Adobe Air is [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/flex_ide.html). IDEA also has all the features of WebStorm.

Comment: But IntelliJ IDEA only supports ActionScript AIR projects, not JavaScript AIR projects.  The OP was asking about JavaScript AIR projects.  Again, I would love to be wrong about this, but I can't find anything about JavaScript AIR support in IntelliJ IDEA.